# browser extensions for multiple sessions in firefox / chrome

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, google-chrome, plugins

I am looking for plugins that I can install with which I can have multiple sessions on my browsers. The answers I have found till now are either outdated, or suggest private browsing, or use .exe extinsions which I can't run in linux

Chromium 24, FireFox 24, Ububtu 12.04

Comment: [Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko?hl=en)

Comment: All of them?  Firefox has had multiple profiles built in from the beginning

Comment: @Paul I am not looking for multiple profiles. What I want to achieve is, sign into the same websites with 2 or 3 different credentials, at the same time. Setting up profiles on FF, or accounts on chrome seem like an overkill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found out what I was looking for

Chrome - [Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko?hl=en)

FireFox - [MultiFox](http://br.mozdev.org/multifox/)